# Maximal Ergodic Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, statistical-mechanics

Does the maximal ergodic theorem have any dynamical or qualitative interpretations, or is it just a custom-made theorem to leave the demonstration of the Birkhoff ergodic theorem more elegant?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73248/applications-of-and-motivation-for-von-neumanns-mean-ergodic-theorem

Comment: Excuse me, but I could not understand what this discussion has to do with the maximal ergodic theorem?

Comment: It might not. But it gives, in particular, a "qualitative interpretation" of the mean ergodic theorem; specifically, Von Neumann thought the Mean ET was sufficient for a certain physical scenario. Since the two theorems are related (though to what extent I know not), there might be some way to understand a physical interpretation of the Maximal ET.

Answer (score 1):

The answer apparently is yes, a theorem is technical, the deltalhes are given in the article below:

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-15/issue-6/Birkhoffs-ergodic-theorem-and-the-maximal-ergodic-theorem/10.3792/pia/1195579375.full)